# How to output the alert into rows per click instead of per variable

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, alert

[image: 1]

```
function getCheckbox() {
var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
  var id_value = '';
  var title_value = '';
  var type_value = '';
  var date_value = '';
  var url_value = '';
for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
  if (checks[i].checked === true) {
  var row = checks[i].closest('tr');
  id_value += checks[i].value + " ";
  title_value += row.querySelector('.checks-title').textContent + " ";
  type_value += row.querySelector('.checks-type h6').textContent + " ";
  date_value += row.querySelector('.checks-date').textContent + " ";
  url_value += row.querySelector('.checks-url a').getAttribute('href') + " ";
        }
    }

var check_result = "ID: " + id_value + "\nTitle: " + title_value + "\nType: " + type_value + "\nDate: " + date_value + "\nURL: " + url_value;
alert (check_result);
}
```

(the example shows that I have three rows selected)

what I am trying to achieve is something like:

- ID, Title, Type, Date, URL
- ID, Title, Type, Date, URL
- ID, Title, Type, Date, URL

Instead I currently have: (refer to screenshot)

- ID, ID, ID
- Title, Title, Title
- Type, Type, Type
- Date, Date, Date
- URL, URL, URL

what should I change in my var check_result to get what I need?

Comment: You are specifically concatenating all the values by type in the loop `title_value += row.querySelector('.checks-title').textContent + " ";` etc. Just create the line you want on each iteration and push it to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding each check into a variable by type, create an array that will hold each row as a string (`rows`). Then, append each column of the row into a temporary string (`str`), and then push that string as a new element of the `rows` array.

Then, to print your rows, first, create a header row, then use `.join('\n')` on your array to join each element (which are the row strings) by newlines, thus putting each row an a new line.

Just like this:

```
function getCheckbox() {
  var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
  var rows = [];
  for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    if (checks[i].checked === true) {
      var str = "";
      var row = checks[i].closest('tr');
      str += checks[i].value + " ";
      str += row.querySelector('.checks-title').textContent + " ";
      str += row.querySelector('.checks-type h6').textContent + " ";
      str += row.querySelector('.checks-date').textContent + " ";
      str += row.querySelector('.checks-url a').getAttribute('href') + " ";
      rows.push(str);
    }
  }

  var header = "ID, Title, Type, Date, URL\n";
  alert(header + rows.join('\n'));
}
```